# In need of an open source text language translation api

Tags: android, api, cordova, open-source, google-translate

I have read other posts related to this but I haven't got anything concrete.

I am developing an android app using phonegap which needs some sort of text translation. So I searched google translate api but they are charging price for it. They haven't make it available for testing also.

So I moved to bing translate but not sure whether we can use it for android or not. If we can use then how can we use it using jQuery. I have searched a lot but not getting any concrete information.

So someone please suggest Is there anyway by which google can give their translate api for testing

OR

A way to use bing translate api for android app for just testing purpose

OR

Any open source api which can do this thing for me.

**please explain with some example**

Comment: see this  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translate_Toolkit

Comment: You can try http://transltr.org/ it's completely free.

Comment: 2022 reference : https://libretranslate.com/

Answer (score 11):

Found a useful link:[**Free/open-source machine translation software**](http://www.computing.dcu.ie/~mforcada/fosmt.html)

I think you can try some Rule-Based Translator like [**Apertium**](http://www.apertium.org/), [**Anusaaraka**](http://anusaaraka.iiit.ac.in/), [**OpenLogos**](http://logos-os.dfki.de/) or [**Maxin**](http://matxin.sf.net/). But I think statistical machine translation systems can provide better translation quality if get adequate training. [**Moses**](http://www.statmt.org/moses/) has the widest community support and has been tried out by many localization companies and researchers. You can take a look at its translation quality [here](http://matrix.statmt.org) based on different training data and languages.

Other Option（You have to rely on network, they are not open sourced):

[**Microsoft Translator APIs**](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/dev/)
Microsoft Translator APIs provides Ajax, SOAP, HTTP accesses, it requires registration. But it is free. I think the [Bing Translation API](http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/using-the-free-bing-translation-apis) relies on it.

[**Mygengo Translation API**](http://mygengo.com/api/)
Gengo requires you to create an account first.

[**WebServiceX Translate API**](http://www.webservicex.net/ws/wsdetails.aspx?wsid=63)
A free webservice. Check its [wsdl](http://www.webservicex.net/TranslateService.asmx?WSDL)

[**Yandex API**](http://api.yandex.com/translate/doc/dg/reference/translate.xml)

Comment: I am lokking for an open source api like google translate

Comment: Yandex is pretty good. Not sure how accurate it is (I don't speak Chinese!), but it's free and APPEARS to have no limit..

Comment: @AndrewSmiley it has limit on text content limit and no. of request in time limit.

Comment: >Found a useful link:Free/open-source machine translation software

Comment: For anyone still looking for this, YANDEX API is no longer free :(