# Using Python Library for Translating French to English

Tags: python, translation, french

i saw many posts on this one but not really sure which is the best library that does translate from French to English. I have some 10,000 records extracted from a French website and want to translate them in to English. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 5):

Broadly, two available options are offline and online translators. The biggest tradeoff is performance vs. goodness of translation, where offline translators will be much faster while APIs provided by Google/MS will result in better translation but will require one HTTP request per translation.

You can find a good list of offline translators in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108313/in-need-of-an-open-source-text-language-translation-api).

For online translation, [Translator API](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/translatorapi.aspx) is a very common choice to start with, since Google Translate API removed the free quota.